# Flutter Newb, anyone tell me whats wrong with this code?

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

Following a tutorial for adding and saving images and getting errors for the below code, under ImagePicker, ImageSource and SelectedImage.

```
Future getImage() async {
var image = await ImagePicker.PickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

setState(() {
  selectedimage = image;
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an instance first, then you will be able to use `pickImage` method.

```dart
Future getImage() async {
  XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  if (image != null) {
    setState(() {
      selectedimage = image;
    });
  }
}
```

Fine more about [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful whenever playing with the setState() functions. This combined with how you pick the image and how you store it in the 'var' in your case could cause further trouble. To generally ease things up for further use I recommend creating a utils class, in which you would have an image picker method, just like this one:

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? _file = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
  if (_file != null) {
    return await _file.readAsBytes();
  }
  print('No Image Selected');
}
```

Afterwards, if you would like to call that in any other instance you would need something like this, though this is for a url image(I had it in hand), such as:

```
  void selectImage() async {
    Uint8List? im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);

    final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(
            "url for template image"))
        .load("");
    final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();

    // if null - use the template image
    im ??= bytes;

    // update state
    setState(() {
      _image = im!;
    });
  }
```

Hope it helped in a way.

Comment: thanks everyone, some really useful answers here.